# Foreign function call to a base package in R

Tags: r

I'm writing a new R function that uses a modified version of the `cor` function (i.e. cor2), to do this I used the bare bone of the native cor function. In the original code is present a call to a `C_cor` function in the package stats. I try to run the cor2 function but I get the following error:

`Error: object 'C_cor' not found`.

I modified the call to the compiled function from

`.Call(C_cor, x2, y2, 1L, method == 'kendall')`

to

`.Call(stats:::C_cor, x2, y2, 1L, method == 'kendall')`.

After that all works fine.

When I try the `R CMD check` command to verify the package I'm working to, I get:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
Unexported object imported by a ':::' call: ‘stats:::C_cor’
  See the note in ?`:::` about the use of this operator.
See the information on DESCRIPTION files in the chapter ‘Creating R
packages’ of the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
```

and :

```
* checking foreign function calls ... WARNING
Foreign function call to a base package:
  .Call(stats:::C_cor, ...)
Packages should not make .C/.Call/.External/.Fortran calls to a base
package. They are not part of the API, for use only by R itself and
subject to change without notice.
```

I read the 'Writing Extension' manual but I've not been able to solve the problem. I also tried to find the C_cor funcion in the stats package (from a fresh R download) as suggested by Uwe Ligge but I haven't find it. I read a previous discussion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515358/rcmd-check-unexported-objects-imported-by-calls) but I still haven't find how to solve my problem.

Do you have any suggestion on how can I overcame the NOTE and the WARNING from the R CMD check?

All the best

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't ... which will stop you from getting the package onto CRAN, but not from using it for your own purposes ...

Comment: the fact is that I have to get it into the bioconductor's repos

Comment: Someone else may have a better idea, but I would guess your only CRAN/Bioconductor-compatible choice will be to copy whatever you need from https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fbf5cdf29d923395b537a9893f46af1aa75e38f3/src/library/stats/src/cov.c ...

Comment: Does this also get picked up?  `.Call('C_cor', x2, y2, 1L, method == 'kendall', PACKAGE='stats')`

Comment: I get an error:`Error in .Call("C_cor", x2, y2, 1L, method == "kendall", PACKAGE = "stats"): 
  "C_cor" not available for .Call() for package "stats"`